# I am starting my coding experience in Java and I am trying to write a grocery checkout program using arrays and methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods

How do I pass arrays as parameters and then return arrays from the user defined methods to the main method. Here is part of my code.
public static void main(String[] args) {
int size, i=0, ch;

```
    //Initializing scanner declaring arrays
    Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in); 
    int quantity[]=new int[3];
    String name[]=new String[3];
    double price[]=new double [3];

    //do while loop to continue entering items until quantity is 0
    do
    {

        System.out.println("Enter quantity of item, " + "name of item, " + " and price of item, " );
        quantity[i]= scan.nextInt();
        name[i]=scan.next();
        price[i]=scan.nextDouble();
        i++;
    }while(quantity[i]==0);


    //menu for grocery list operations using switch block
    System.out.println("1) Add item(s)/n"
            + "2) Remove item(s)/n"
            + "3) view cart/n "
            + "4) Checkout/n "
            + "5) Exit/n");
    ch=scan.nextInt();
    switch(ch) 
    {
    case 1: 


        add(quantity[i-1],name[i-1],price[i-1]);
        break;
```

And here is the method  add

```
//method to add item
public static  void add(int q,String  n,double p )

{
    Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter quantity of item, " + "name of item, " + " and price of item, " );
    q=scan.nextInt();
    n= scan.next();
    p=scan.nextDouble(); 
    scan.close();


}
```

Comment: Don't use arrays, they are terrible.  Use a collection, such as a `List`

Comment: Why do you think arrays are terrible?

Comment: @DwB Please substantiate your (bold) claim.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing arrays, you can run the SWITCH STATEMENT inside a FOR LOOP upto the length of the Array.

Comment: Great Idea! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Passing arrays as parameters and returning arrays in java is straightforward.

Here is an example:

```
public static int[] foo(int[] a){
    // Do something with a
    int[] b = {0,1,2};
    return b;
}
```

But also keep in mind that Java is pass by value, but when you pass an array in as a parameter, it passes the reference (AKA memory address) as a value to the function.

Why is this important?
It means that you can manipulate all the values of an array you pass as a parameter and these changes will be noticed in a different method.

Example:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    int b = 5;
    foo1(b);
    // b is still 5


    int[] c = {1,2};
    foo2(c);
    // c is now {1,10} 
}

public static void foo1(int x){
    x = 10;
}

public static void foo2(int[] x){
    x[1] = 10;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the clarification

Comment: No problem! If you feel the answer is good, feel free to mark it as accepted.